# What class does getFirstName() belong to when authenticating using Play Services

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-play-services

Ok I'm refering the Android-Google docs here:
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/auth.html

It has this part of code where it calls getFirstName() without using any object. I'm not able to guess what class's object to make or implement/extend.

here's that part of the code, rest everything is on that link:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=" + token);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int serverCode = con.getResponseCode();
//successful query
if (serverCode == 200) {
    InputStream is = con.getInputStream();
    String name = getFirstName(readResponse(is)); //THIS LINE!!
    mActivity.show("Hello " + name + "!");
    is.close();
    return;
//bad token, invalidate and get a new one
} else if (serverCode == 401) {
    GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(mActivity, token);
    onError("Server auth error, please try again.", null);
    Log.e(TAG, "Server auth error: " + readResponse(con.getErrorStream()));
    return;
//unknown error, do something else
} else {
    Log.e("Server returned the following error code: " + serverCode, null);
    return;
}
```

Edit: I want to use the method getFirstName() but I'm getting 'cannot be resolved' errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at `<android-sdk>/extras/google-play-services/samples/auth/AbstractGetNameTask.java`, you can see the definition of `getFirstname`:

```
private String getFirstName(String jsonResponse) throws JSONException {
  JSONObject profile = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
  return profile.getString(NAME_KEY);
}
```

`NAME_KEY` is defined earlier in that file:

```
private static final String NAME_KEY = "given_name";
```

If you cannot find that file in your Android SDK directory, open the Android SDK Manager and download "Google Play services".

Comment: yes that file is there and I have downloaded Google Play Services from SDK manager.
My problem is I'm using getFirstname just as shown in the guide but I'm getting 'getFirstname cannot be resolved' error.
I probably need to inherit a class but I don't know which one

Comment: You'll need to copy the function into your file, then.